# Calling bindService in android

Tags: android, service

I am calling `bind()` from `onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)` in **MyFragment.class** And in `onResume()` I am trying to access **mSerive** But it shows **NULL POINTER EXCEPTION**, the `onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)` calls after the `onResume()`. Why the onServiceConnected is not called when I called `bind()` can anyone give the suggestion about it?

```
private final ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        try {
            mService.unregisterCallback(mCallback.this);
            mService = null;
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        try {
            mService = IService.Stub.asInterface(service);
            mService.registerCallback(mCallback.this);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }
};

public void bind() {
    if (!mServiceConnected) {
        mServiceConnected = true;
        Intent connectionIntent = new Intent(IService.class.getName());
        mActivity.bindService(connectionIntent, mServiceConnection,
                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

    } 
}
```

Comment: what 'onService' are you talking about?

Comment: onServiceConnected() which is in ServiceConnection

Comment: connection is made async so you cannot make any assumptions if its made before onResume or not

Comment: but If I use the same service in Activity extended class it binds the serviceconnection perfectly while calling bind().. But it wont occur in myfragment

Comment: so onServiceConnected is never called?

Comment: I called bind() in onCreateView() on my Fragment class and mServiceConnection called after onResume() but I need to access mService the starting of my fragment class.. If I try this it shows null pointer exception

Comment: i already told you that binding is done async and you cannot change that,

Comment: then can you suggest me how can I access mService while enter my fragment view

Comment: if onServiceConnected is called later you simply cannod do anything

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one

```
 // inapp
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(
            "com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
    serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

    bindService = bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConn,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```